# How to apply CSS conditionally

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to add a css in ng-template. I have following html code.

It was possible to set a condition for my css in div tag but If I were to do the same thing in ng-template, it throws me the Template parse error msg.

Is there any way I can set a condition in css inside of ng-template? `class.blink` is supposed to blink element when the condition is met.

```
 <span id="AOR23" class="style161" style="font-size:Small;"*ngIf="this.date == null; else RgetDate"></span>

 <ng-template #RgetDate [class.blink] = "condition">{{data.grade}}</ng-template>
```

**error**

> Property binding blink not used by any directive on an embedded template

Comment: You can use `ngClass` directive. For example see https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: `ng-template` produces no html tag, therefore you can't style it. You may be looking for the `span` html tag.

Comment: @Ploppy I have to use ng-template in order to get the else statement(RgetDate) in span.. is there other way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, did not noticed you are using ng-template. To apply any style attribute, you must use some HTML tag.

Comment: @SomnathSinha so there is no way to set condition in ng-template? I simply wanted to blink the data when meets the condition.

Comment: so in my span, i have condition ngIf="this.date == null. If this is true then it displays the value, else display data.grade.. and I want to apply animation here.. not sure how I should proceed from here

Comment: Whay don't you try something like this `<ng-template #RgetDate><span [class.blink]="condition"> {{data.grade}}</span></ng-template>`

Comment: I think your all setup is wrong an you are making everything complicated, what do you want to do exactly? (why would you have a span, with no content and a condition ??? Is this a typo or are there both `date` and `data`?)